# Python 3.2 Debug Lib

Tags: python, linker-errors

I need to either download or build the python32_d.lib, unfortunately whenever I search for how to obtain said lib all I get is people asking the same question, but never the actual answer. 
One answer was to #undef _DEBUG, but upon doing this I get an Iterator_Debug_Level linker error in the project. 
So how do I actually get the python32_d.lib?

Comment: I'm trying to get 3.1 to work in VC++2010 Express and have had the same problem. I managed to link against Python31.lib. Are you sure you're un-defining `_DEBUG` throughout your project, or merely where you include python headers? Remove it from the pre-processor settings and [switch to release CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b98s6w8.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you building with MSVC? [This](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Building%20Python%20with%20the%20free%20MS%20C%20Toolkit) should get you started.

Comment: what I dont understand is why they dont just distribute the pythonXX_d.lib and pythonXX_d.dll, I have to download the source. Then download its dependencies, then compile its dependencies, so I can build myself some debug lib and dll! Just because I like programming doesn't mean I like compiling EVERYTHING!..... =(

Comment: Umm... Compiling and understanding how things build is a crucial to programming. Each .lib and how they link to its client is very dependent to the compiler. It can't simply be redistributed since their purpose is to be compiled along with other/your binaries, and not simply be executed. The former is very dependent on your build environment and toolchain. The latter is not.

Comment: I do understand compiling and how they link together. But when you install it ships with python32.lib and python32.dll. They have multiple installers on their site, and should have the different versions available, like many other libraries I use...